# How to run openmpi on virtualbox with 3 PCs through SSH?

Tags: virtualbox, ssh, nat

I have 3 PCs with Vista, running Ubuntu through Virtualbox on them. I have installed `openmpi` and `ssh` on them, they are connected via ethernet. The IP addresses are all `10.0.2.15`. And I can ping with my Windows IP Address. But the problem is that when I type:

```
SSH x.x.x.x
```

I receive this error:

```
ssh : connect to host x.x.x.x port 22 : connection timed out.
```

I'd be glad if someone could help me!

Comment: Please don't obfuscate essential parts of your command.

Comment: How are you VMs networks configured?. NAT?. Bridge?. This IP number suggest NAT.